# R - I want to go through rows of a big matrix and remove all zeros

Tags: r, matrix, row

I have a lot of rows and columns in a very large matrix (184 x 4000, type double), and I want to remove all 0's. The values in the matrix are usually greater than 0 but there are some rows of 0.0000 . I tried to remove the rows with zeros using this:

```
x <- x[which(rowSums(x) > 0),]
```

but what I am left with is a mere 3 rows out of 184. And I know for a fact that the deleted 181 rows were not all 0 rows. 
Does anyone have a clue why this is happening and how I can fix it? I used this same code on a different matrix with the same structure (184 rows, 4000 columns) and it worked. What am I missing?

Comment: You want to remove all rows that contain 1 or more 0s or do you want to remove all rows that contain _only_ 0s?

Comment: rows that contain ONLY 0s

Comment: I think you should paste the output of `dput(novm[1:10, 1:5])` and your expected output

Comment: @akrun how about now? Sorry, I am rather inexperienced in R.

Comment: @AC11 that looks fine. but what is your expected result?  If you check `x`, it doesn't have any NA values nor 0

Comment: @akrun Oh I understand now. Well, way down the matrix, there are a few rows that do entail 0.0000. And NA's. I took the NA's out in the beginning. But after using x <- x[!rowSums(!x)==ncol(x),], all elements (0 or nonzero) are turned into NAs, and after using x <- x[!apply(x == 0, 1, all), , drop = FALSE] , the 0's aren't removed.

Comment: @AC11 Did you tried `x[!(rowSums(!is.na(x) & !x)+rowSums(is.na(x)))==ncol(x),]`

Comment: @akrun I just did, it didn't change anything :(

Comment: @AC11.  Suppose I named the matrix as `x` and `x[2,] <- 0;x[2,3] <- NA; x[4,1:3] <- 0; x[!(rowSums(!is.na(x) & !x)+rowSums(is.na(x)))==ncol(x),]` deletes the 2nd row

Comment: @AC11, there is something wrong.  Can you share the data on dropbox or something?  I can take a look at it.

Comment: @akrun for some reason, the NAs are being removed, however all cells with 0.0000's are still there. could this have anything to do with the fact that we specify "0" and not "0.0000" in the function?

Comment: @AC11 check the str() of the dataset.  I guess these columns are not "numeric"?

Comment: @akrun they are double! could this be the problem?

Comment: @AC11. Check if those elements (0.0000) subtracted from 0 gives you 0 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have the answer. The reason why

```
x<- x[which(rowSums(x) > 0),]
```

only returned 3 rows out of 184 was because this function only gives you those rows that do not sum up to 0 and/or do not have an NA in them. And I had a few NA's in all but 3 rows, I just wasn't aware of. 
Simply taking out the NA's did not work, because that didn't solve the rowSums problem. 
I needed the function to treat my NA's as zeros, so that the rows that did entail NA's (as in all but 3) would also be summed up and not just taken out of the matrix. So I turned all NA's into zeros by using

```
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```

and THEN applying the function to sum up all rows and remove the ones that add up to 0. And it worked!
Thanks to everyone for your input. Especially @arkun!

Answer (score 3):

You can drop rows which only contain 0s like this (and you could replace 0 with any other number if you wanted to drop rows with only that number):

```
x <- x[rowSums(x == 0) != ncol(x),]
```

Explanation:

- `x == 0` creates a matrix of logical values (TRUE/FALSE) and
  `rowSums(x == 0)` sums them up (TRUE == 1, FALSE == 0).
- Then you check if the sum of each row is *not* equal to the number of columns
  of your matrix (which are counted by `ncol(x)`).
- If that is the case (which means not all entries are 0s), the row will be kept because it
  evaluates to TRUE. All other rows evaluate to FALSE and will be dropped.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I replace the x with my matrix name right?

Comment: for some reason doing this returns me a matrix of all NAs except for the very same three rows that it left me in my initial attempt. This also happens when I try to implement the suggestion that @akrun provided. I'm confused :/

Comment: @AC11, then something may be wrong with your matrix. Can you post an example of your data? and the output of `str(yourmatrix)`?

Comment: @AC11, please edit your question and include the data there so others dont need to read the comments to find this information. you'll also be able to format it right then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for removing the rows that contain only zeros.

```
x[!apply(x == 0, 1, all), , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
x[!rowSums(!x)==ncol(x),] #could be shortened to

x[!!rowSums(abs(x)),] #Inspired from @Richard Scriven
```

#### data

```
 x <- structure(list(V1 = c(2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3), V2 = c(2, 
   0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 
  1), V4 = c(3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), V5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

- `!x`. Creates a logical index of TRUE and FALSE, where TRUE will be elements that are 0's
- `rowSums(!x)`. rowwise Sum of those TRUEs,
- `==ncol(x)`.  Check whether the sum is equal to the number of columns.  In the above example it is 5.  That means all entries are 0
- `!` Negate again because we want to filter out these rows
- Subset `x` using this logical index

#### Update

Suppose you have NA's in your dataset and you want to remove rows with all 0's or those with 0's and NA's, for e.g.

```
 x <-   structure(list(V1 = c(2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3), V2 = c(2, 
 NA, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(3, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 
 1), V4 = c(3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, 1), V5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L), class = "data.frame")

 x[!(rowSums(!is.na(x) & !x)+rowSums(is.na(x)))==ncol(x),]
```

- The idea is to first sum the NAs rowwise
- Rowwise sum of all the elements that are not NAs and are 0's `rowSUms(!is.na(x) & !x)`
- Take the sum of the above two.  If that number matches with the number of columns, delete that row

Comment: Thank you akrun. 
x[!rowSums(!x)==ncol(x),] makes NAs out of every Element in the Matrix. What could be the reason?

Comment: @AC11.  Are you talking about `x` that has NAs`.  In that case check the output of `!x`.  You will see that `NA` remain as such. So, rowSums(!x) still have NAs, unless you have `rowSums(!x, na.rm=T)`

Comment: I first removed all NAs so that they don't mess up the sum when attempting to remove all zero rows. Then applied your suggestion to my data and received a matrix full of NAs. If I forgo my first step (i.e not removing all NAs first), the same thing happens.

Comment: @AC11. Could you show a small reproducible example using `dput`, (just like I showed above), also your expected output. For example `dput(head(data, 20))`

Comment: Just edited my Question! Check Edit#2. Let me know if its not enough or you want me to add further details-

Comment: @ACII. I checked the edit#2. I don't think it is enough.  Use `dput(novm[1:10, 1:5]))`.  This will have 10 rows and 5 columns.  In your output, it looks like a vector.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, slightly change of @Richard Scriven:

```
remove_zeros<- function(x)
{
  x = x[!apply(x == 0, 1, all),]
  return(x)
}
```