# How to filter gene expression data set with rows equal to zeros?

Tags: r

I want to remove rows in a expression data-set whose values is altogether zero, I did search and found the code below I'm not sure how its working can anyone explain me `[(3:col(df))]]==0)==col(df)-2, ]` what this argument means?

```
df[ !(df[rownames(df),[(3:col(df))]]==0)==col(df)-2, ]
```

Comment: well I already have negative votes for the question but can anyone explain me?

Comment: the code is garbled (where did you find it??) and you haven't given a reproducible example.

Comment: okay i will cite the source

Comment: @BenBolker my source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203813/remove-rows-from-dataframe-that-contains-only-0-or-just-a-single-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of clunky code, and it seems to be a bit garbled.

```
df[rowSums(df[,3:ncol(df)]==0)!=ncol(df)-2,]
```

would select the rows of the data frame where the last (ncol-2) of the columns are not all zero.

- `df[,3:ncol(df)]` selects all but the first two columns
- `rowSums(.==0)` counts the number of zeros in each row
- `. != ncol(df)-2` is `TRUE` for all entries where the number of zeros is not equal to the number of (remaining) columns
- `df[.,]` selects rows

A slightly simpler alternative would be

```
df[any(df[,-(1:2)]!=0),]
```

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, StackOverflow deprecates [using comments to say "thank you"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged?lq=1); if this answer was useful you can upvote it (if you have sufficient reputation), and in any case if it answers your question satisfactorily you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.